# Jmeter two response code assertion

Tags: jmeter, http-response-codes

I already made Response Code 422 as a success http request in jmeter with Response Assertion, and it works. But jmeter assign Response Code 200 as a failed http request.

I add 422 and 200 in Pattern to test but jmeter only assert Response Code 200 as a success http request.

How assign Response Code 200 OR 422 as a success http request?

regards,
Stefio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`200|422`

The pipe character `|` is the OR operator

In general, you can use perl5 regular expressions in JMeter

Comment: thank you, its work. I forgot to select "Contains" in Pattern Matching Rules (radio button select "Equal"). That's why jmeter always search equality.

Comment: The "Ignore Status" checkbox should be checked, otherwise 422 will lead fail status.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a beanshell post processor to write a short beanshell script to change the status from "fail" to "pass" if the code is 422.

Answer (score -1):

Assert the text/Response code by using Response Assertion. Click here [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSqPb.jpg) for solution.